# Многотабличный SQL запрос для вывода сообщений

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица user_message 
`id
id_from
id_for
message`

И есть таблица users 
`id
username`

Мне нужно вывести `message и username` где `id_from = $_SESSION['id']` и `id_for = $_POST['id']`

id_from и id_for должны соответсвствовать id в таблице users и вместо id-шек выводится username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно отталкиваться от следующего решения

```
<?php
  session_start();
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "SELECT
                m.message AS message,
                fu.username AS from_username,
                tu.username AS for_username
              FROM
                user_message AS m
              LEFT JOIN
                users AS fu
              ON
                m.id_from = fu.id
              LEFT JOIN
                users AS tu
              ON
                m.id_for = tu.id
              WHERE
                m.id_from IN (:id_from, :id_for) AND
                m.id_for IN (:id_from, :id_for)";
    $msg = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $msg->execute(['id_from' => $_SESSION['id'], 'id_from' => $_POST['id']]);
    $user = $msg->fetchAll();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка ".$e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: Для меня ООП как иероглифы ) Я учусь и скоро доберемся до ООП. Я пробовал скопировать, но кроме ошибки ничего не получил. Вы не могли бы разобрать следующую строчку: fu.username AS from_username, tu.username AS for_username?

Comment: fu.username - это обращение к полю username таблице username AS fu, При помощи ключевого слова AS мы назначаем псевдоним столбцу в результирующей таблице, чтобы было удобнее обращаться к нему в конечном результирующем массиве $user. А какое сообщение об ошибке выводится? Скрипту передаются POST-данные и данные в сессии?

Comment: По разбирался немного, мне кажется у вас ошибка, есть таблица users , таблицы username не существует, потом, где id_from => $_POST , вместо from надо for , правильно?

Comment: Ошибку выдает следующую : 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id_from AND
                m.id_for = :id_for
              LIMIT 1' at line 16

Comment: 1) Вы правы, поправил название таблицы users. 2) Если вы выполняете запрос в консоли, то :id_from и :id_for следует заменить числовыми значениями. В примере выше они заменяются на этапе вызова метода execute().

Comment: Попробовал в консоли, выводит только отправленные сообщения от id_from к id_for, но получается мне надо вывести и ответы пользователя id_for.

Comment: Попробуйте исправленный вариант

Comment: Спасибо! ) заработало! Чтобы я без вас делал!

Answer (score 3):

Вот что вам нужно. Значения сессии и поста лучше записать в отдельную переменную.

```
$from = $_SESSION['id'];
$for = $_POST['id'];
$sql ="SELECT
       (SELECT u.username FROM  users u WHERE m.id_from = u.id) AS 'from',
       (SELECT u.username FROM  users u WHERE m.id_for = u.id) AS 'for',
       m.message
       FROM user_message m
       WHERE m.id_from = $from
       AND m.id_for = $for"
```

Comment: Спасибо, а вы не подскажете где можно почитать про запросы, а то я не все понял из написанного и почему лучше записывать в переменные?

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан Вот в переменные точно не надо записывать и самое главное их нельзя подствалять в текст запроса. Потому как прислав вам специально подмененное значение можно легко модифицировать этим запрос и выполнить произвольный код, т.е. произвести sql-инъекцию. Надо использовать привязываемые переменные. например для pdo: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан Посмотрите здесь [ruhighload.com](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL)

Comment: @Mike Это почему в переменные нельзя записывать? По вашему лучше было сразу $_SESSION['id']; и $_POST['id']; написать что ли?

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev Да понятно что в сами переменные можно, только подставлять их непосредственно в текст запроса не стоит. Это я еще не указал, что многие СУБД кешируют планы выполнения и когда надо выполнить полностью, до буквы идентичный запрос - делают это быстрее. Но если подставлять значения в текст запроса непосредственно то план будет строится каждый раз, плюс ко всему забивая SQL-кеш. С привязываемыми переменными этой проблемы нет, т.к. сам текст запроса всегда одинаков

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev Попробовал ваш способ, где то ошибка? Выводит не все сообщения + вместо username (undefined) ((

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить запрос выше в консоли, подставив числовые значения. Результат возвращается корректный? Может значение переменной теряется где-то в другом месте?